# Including JS script conditional to user device

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I need to load a script conditionally so that it only loads on desktop/laptops. I need it NOT to show on mobile/tablet. (So I'm guessing filtering by screen width would be best.)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.php?zoneid=354066'></script>
```

I've looked at including it like this to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";

if (screen.width > 500)
{
}
else
{
    js.src = "//xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.php?zoneid=354066";
}

head.appendChild(js);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `navigator.userAgent`. You should replace `.match(/Mac/)` with the pattern for the type of desktop you're looking to target. You can also use "or" -- `||` to check for multiple types of desktops :

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

if (ua.match(/Mac/) != null){ 
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = "//xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.php?zoneid=354066'";

  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.appendChild(js);
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this by screen width instead of user agent?

Comment: Yes--you can use the `screen` object to get `screen.width` and `screen.height`. Using the code I've laid out above you can replace the statement in the `if` check to check against `screen.width`